# Some issues with AspNet Core SignalR KeepAlive timeout

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

In our project I have set the SignalR as follow :

```
services.AddSignalR()
            .AddHubOptions<NotificationHub>(options =>
            {
                const int keepAliveIntervalInSeconds=60;
                options.EnableDetailedErrors=true;
                options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2 * keepAliveIntervalInSeconds);
                options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(keepAliveIntervalInSeconds);
                options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(keepAliveIntervalInSeconds);
            });
```

but it is not working as it supposed to do. I am getting an error in the client that says :

```
[2020-06-03T09:48:44.367Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'.
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: @sommmen it is 60 seconds. Do you mean that the handshake timeout should be also greater than the interval ?

Comment: my mistake - i read it wrong. I'm unsure - i haven't touched these settings they seem appropriate for whatever im doing. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'

In [the "Configure server options" section of this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options-1), we can find:

*The default value of `KeepAliveInterval` is **15 seconds**. When changing `KeepAliveInterval`, we need to change the `ServerTimeout/serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` setting **on the client side** too. And the recommended `ServerTimeout/serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` value is double the `KeepAliveInterval` value.*

And the default timeout value of [serverTimeoutInMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#servertimeoutinmilliseconds) is 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds), if you just update `KeepAliveInterval` setting of your SignalR hub to **60 seconds** but not change the `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` value on your client side, which would cause above error.

Comment: It turned out that the client settings would be suffice for what  I had in mind.