# How to extend Session Idle Timeout in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, session, .net-core

Current state:
The session expires after 40 minutes of inactivity, although the session idle timeout is set to four hours in the Startup.cs file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSession(options => {
     options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
   });
}
```

Target state:
The session should expire after four hours at the earliest.

I have tried to set the session state timeout in the IIS manager, but it didn't work aswell.

[session state in IIS manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQyud.png)

Comment: Is the session timing out or is the connection between client and host closing?  The connection timeout is usually solved by implementing a Keep-Alive.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169959/some-issues-with-aspnet-core-signalr-keepalive-timeout?force_isolation=true

Comment: I suggest you could also check the cookie timeout value to make sure the cookie is also exceed 4 hours. Since the cookie will store the session ID. Besides, if the session cookies are deleted when the browser session ends.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the **app.UseSession()** command in the configuration of the HTTP request pipeline (Startup.cs)?

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: This answer could be a comment. then the question author can improve the question to respond to you about app.UseSession()

Comment: I tried but couldn't comment as I don't have enough reputation. You can only comment after 50 points.

I can only comment on my own solutions.